# No installed apps

Tags: applications

I removed three apps that I never use from my phone so I would have more storage. Now I can't update any apps because I have no installed apps. How can I fix this without a factory reset?

Comment: More details please

Answer (score 0):

Go to recovery , wipe cache.

Or

Uninstall all apps, remove corresponding folders from `{default storage}/android/data` and again install apps.